# How to connect with Python IMAP4_SSL and self-signed server SSL cert?

Tags: python, ssl-certificate, imaplib

I'm using python3 and `imaplib` to connect to an Exchange server. The Exchange server uses a self-signed certificate created for the hostname 'my.server.fqdn'. After a recent OS upgrade on my workstation (Ubuntu 14.04) my python script no longer works.

The basic snippet of code I'm using is here:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import imaplib
import socket
import ssl
import getpass

passwd = getpass.getpass()
mail =  imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('my.server.fqdn', 1143)  
mail.login('mike', passwd)
mail.list()
mail.select("INBOX")
```

The code worked fine prior to the upgrade. Now this code produces this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./example.py", line 9, in <module>
    mail =  imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('my.server.fqdn', 1143)  
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/imaplib.py", line 1222, in __init__
    IMAP4.__init__(self, host, port)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/imaplib.py", line 181, in __init__
    self.open(host, port)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/imaplib.py", line 1236, in open
    IMAP4.open(self, host, port)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/imaplib.py", line 257, in open
    self.sock = self._create_socket()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/imaplib.py", line 1228, in _create_socket
    server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/ssl.py", line 364, in wrap_socket
    _context=self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/ssl.py", line 578, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/ssl.py", line 805, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_INTERNAL_ERROR] tlsv1 alert internal error (_ssl.c:598)
```

It's not apparent to me if python is having a problem with the self-signed certificate, SSL version, or if there is something new with python 3 which doesn't work with my old code.

I do have a PEM file from the Exchange server which allows me to connect to the server using `curl`. Authentication fails, however the checks `curl` does during the SSL handshake seem to work OK. I do have to supply `curl` the `--sslv3` option along with a path to the PEM file for that to work. If that's what I need to do with python to get this working again, how do I go about supplying python with the same information?

curl session is here:

```
$ curl -vvv --sslv3 https://my.server.fqdn:1143 --cacert ~/my_server_fqdn.pem 
    * Rebuilt URL to: https://my.server.fqdn:1143/
    * Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
    *   Trying 10.10.10.10...
    * Connected to my.server.fqdn (10.10.10.10) port 1143 (#0)
    * successfully set certificate verify locations:
    *   CAfile: /home/username/my_server_fqdn.pem
      CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
    * SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
    * SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
    * SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
    * SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
    * SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
    * SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
    * SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
    * SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
    * SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
    * SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
    * SSL connection using ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
    * Server certificate:
    *        subject: O=fqdn; O=SERVER; OU=M; CN=my.server.fqdn
    *        start date: 2013-07-29 20:59:04 GMT
    *        expire date: 2023-07-27 20:59:04 GMT
    *        common name: my.server.fqdn (matched)
    *        issuer: O=fqdn; O=SERVER; OU=M; CN=my.server.fqdn
    *        SSL certificate verify ok.
    > GET / HTTP/1.1
    > User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
    > Host: my.server.fqdn:1143
    > Accept: */*
    > 
    * OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4REV1 AUTH=LOGIN MOVE] IMAP4rev1 server ready
    GET BAD command authentication required
    User-Agent: BAD command authentication required
    Host: BAD command authentication required
    Accept: BAD command authentication required
    * SSLv3, TLS alert, Client hello (1):
    * Connection #0 to host my.server.fqdn left intact
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apparently this problem is due to one or more [versions of TLS protocol being disabled](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssl/+bug/1256576) in the openssl package on Ubuntu 12.04 and 14.04. I ended up using an ssl context in python3 and forcing SSL version 3 for the connection. This appears to work now. Really hope this helps anyone struggling with the same problem.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import imaplib
import socket
import ssl
import getpass

ctx = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv3)  
passwd = getpass.getpass()
mail =  imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('my.server.fqdn', 1143, ssl_context=ctx)
mail.login('mike', passwd)
mail.select('INBOX', 1)
typ, uids = mail.uid("SEARCH", None, "ALL")

uids = uids[0].split()
for u in uids:
   print ("found uid " , u)

mail.close()
mail.logout()
del mail
```

Comment: How do you install ssl protocol v3

Comment: ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv3 is since 3.6 deprecated (https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv3). You should use default ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS

Comment: or perhaps better yet:
`ctx = ssl.create_default_context()`